Recursively move subtitle files into subdirectories
I currently run plex on a Beelink running ubuntu, and to date, all files associated with each movie (movie file, associated images, and subtitles) are all in the same parent directory. for the most part that's okay, but for movies with multiple subtitles, it can get messy. e.g.
    /Movies
       /Avatar (2009)
          Avatar (2009).mkv
          Avatar (2009).eng.srt
          Avatar (2009).en.forced.ass
          Avatar (2009).en.sdh.srt
          Avatar (2009).de.srt
          Avatar (2009).de.sdh.forced.srt

It seems that now plex will find subtitles places in a "subs" or "subtitles" folder. So in order to tidy things up, how can I recursively go through the parent movie directory, and for each individual movie folder, move any subtitles files into a "subtitles" folder like so?
/Movies
   /Avatar (2009)
      Avatar (2009).mkv
      /Subtitles
         Avatar (2009).eng.srt
         Avatar (2009).en.sdh.srt
         Avatar (2009).de.srt
         Avatar (2009).de.sdh.forced.srt

For TV shows, there may be multiple levels under the parent folder, e.g.
**Old:**


/TV Shows
   /Game Of Thrones
      /Season 02
         Game Of Thrones - s02e03.mp4
         Game Of Thrones - s02e03.eng.srt
         Game Of Thrones - s02e03.en.forced.srt


**New:**
         
TV Shows
   /Game Of Thrones
      /Season 01
         Game Of Thrones - s01e03.mp4
         Game Of Thrones - s01e04.mp4
         /Subtitles
           Game Of Thrones - s01e03.eng.srt
           Game Of Thrones - s01e04.eng.srt
      /Season 02
         Game Of Thrones - s02e03.mp4
         /Subs
           Game Of Thrones - s02e03.eng.srt
           Game Of Thrones - s02e03.en.forced.srt


Even better would be the option to only move if not already in a subtitles folder...

I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but subtitles can be embedded in mkv files. This has been my go-to for a while. Can't get tidier than that. (I assume Plex supports this)

Close voters: how is this not about Ubuntu? The OP is running Ubuntu, what else do you need?

find . -name 'Subtitles' -prune -o -type f -name '*.srt' -printf '%h\0' | sort -zu | while IFS= read -d '' -r d; do
    printf "Creating '%s'...\n" "${d}/Subtitles"
    printf "Moving '%s' to '%s'...\n" "${d}/*.srt" "${d}/Subtitles"
done

Will find the path of every .srt file in the current working directory, recursively, excluding those contained in a directory named "Subtitles", printing only their basename and filtering out duplicates, creating a "Subtitles" directory inside each resulting path (if not existing) and moving every .srt file at its level inside it.
It will deal with .srt files located at any depth of the current working directory, and so with the "TV Shows" directory as well.
The command will perform a dry run; if the output looks good, run the actual command:
find . -name 'Subtitles' -prune -o -type f -name '*.srt' -printf '%h\0' | sort -zu | while IFS= read -d '' -r d; do
    mkdir -p "${d}/Subtitles"
    mv "${d}"/*.srt "${d}/Subtitles"
done


% tree -a
.
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       ├── baz
│       │   └── Subtitles
│       │       └── sub_baz.srt
│       └── sub_bar.srt
└── sub.srt

5 directories, 3 files
% find . -name 'Subtitles' -prune -o -type f -name '*.srt' -printf '%h\0' | sort -zu | while IFS= read -d '' -r d; do
    mkdir -p "${d}/Subtitles"
    mv "${d}"/*.srt "${d}/Subtitles"
done
% tree -a
.
├── foo
│   └── bar
│       ├── baz
│       │   └── Subtitles
│       │       └── sub_baz.srt
│       └── Subtitles
│           └── sub_bar.srt
└── Subtitles
    └── sub.srt

7 directories, 3 files


Probably the easiest way to implement the OP's bonus request to only move if not already in a subtitles directly would be to add a -prune on that to the find command, so sub filenames inside them are never printed. find . -iname Subtitles -prune -o -type f -iname '*.srt' -printf '%h\0' is I think correct.  (Ignoring anything called Subtitles whether it's a file or directory.)

@terdon: yeah, I was afraid it might need grouping.  According to the man page, -prune is "true", like -name '*' but with a side-effect of pruning.  find . \( -iname Subtitles -prune \) -o  \( -type f -iname '*.srt' -printf '%h\0' \) works for me, moving foo/bar/sub.srt to foo/bar/Subtitles/sub.srt but not printing that new filename if run again.

Of course pruning isn't the only option, a simpler-to-understand way is to add -not -path '*/Subtitles/*' which should Just Work at any position before -printf, being implicitly ANDed with -iname and -type.

Yes indeed. So does find .  -name Subtitles -prune -o -iname '*srt' -print. I finally spent more than a minute looking at it, and find's info page is a bit more informative. The prune only blocks descent into the found ditrectory, not printing of the directory itself. So for -prune to be used to hide both the dir and its contents, it needs an OR condition so that the first part of the OR is false and we move to the next. Hence my version which is find ... -o -print.

By the way, @PeterCordes, your first example was also completely correct. I was just testing it wrong! I removed the -printf '%h\0' to make the results easy to read, but since there was no action, the prune wasn't removing the dir itself. Using the -printf or using a simple -print or -print0 makes it work. My bad! I deleted my comment.

@PeterCordes To be honest I didn't even notice OP's request, it was crammed between the example and the tags and I completely missed it, thanks! Especially for providing the -prune solution right away cause I know I would have lost my mind before managing to make it work, I don't know what's wrong with me and -prune, I can never remember how to get it right.

Here's another approach. Use bash's globstar option to allow for recursing into subdirectories. From man bash:

globstar
If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more  directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.

So **/ will only match directories, but it will include sub-directories. With this in mind, you can do:
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/; do mkdir -p "$d/Subtitles" && mv "$d/"*.srt "$d"/Subtitles ; done
rmdir **/Subtitles/

I tested it using this set of files and directories:
$ tree
.
├── a
├── b
├── Movies
│   └── Avatar
│       ├── Avatar (2009).de.sdh.forced.srt
│       ├── Avatar (2009).de.srt
│       ├── Avatar (2009).en.forced.ass
│       ├── Avatar (2009).eng.srt
│       ├── Avatar (2009).en.sdh.srt
│       └── Avatar (2009).mkv
└── TV Shows
    └── Game Of Thrones
        └── Season 02
            ├── Game Of Thrones - s02e03.emg.srt
            ├── Game Of Thrones - s02e03.en.forced.srt
            └── Game Of Thrones - s02e03.mp4

6 directories, 11 files

After running the command above, I ended up with:
$ tree
.
├── a
├── b
├── Movies
│   └── Avatar
│       ├── Avatar (2009).en.forced.ass
│       ├── Avatar (2009).mkv
│       └── Subtitles
│           ├── Avatar (2009).de.sdh.forced.srt
│           ├── Avatar (2009).de.srt
│           ├── Avatar (2009).eng.srt
│           └── Avatar (2009).en.sdh.srt
└── TV Shows
    └── Game Of Thrones
        └── Season 02
            ├── Game Of Thrones - s02e03.mp4
            └── Subtitles
                ├── Game Of Thrones - s02e03.emg.srt
                └── Game Of Thrones - s02e03.en.forced.srt

8 directories, 11 files

Note that it will throw out some warnings for cases where there are no srt files in a directory since it will then try to run mv directory_name/*srt directory_name/Subtitles but since the *.srt glob matches nothing, it will return itself (unless you have the nullglob option activated), and as there is no file whose name is literally *srt, it will fail. This is also why I had to add rmdir **/Subtitles to remove empty Subtitles directories. You can safely add 2> /dev/null to the end of the mv command to hide these warnings.
Alternatively, you can do something slightly more complex and only create the dir and try to copy when you know you have *.srt files:
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for d in **/; do 
  subs=( "$d"/*.srt ) 
  [[ ${#subs[@]} -gt 0 ]] && 
    mkdir -p "$d"/Subtitles && 
      mv "$d"/*srt "$d"/Subtitles
done

Which results in the desired output in a single pass. To avoid moving files if they are already in a Subtitles directory, use the extglob bash option that lets you build more complex globs, and just look for any directory whose name is not Subtitles:
shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
for d in **/!(Subtitles)/; do 
  subs=( "$d"/*.srt ) 
  [[ ${#subs[@]} -gt 0 ]] && 
    mkdir -p "$d"/Subtitles && 
      mv "$d"/*srt "$d"/Subtitles
done


Thanks, @kos and no, I forgot the first one, good catch!
